# Visual Studio 2013 freezing after completing a build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build, settings, freeze

I have encountered a very strange problem and I haven't seen an answer to this anywhere on this forum or others. Yesterday when I pressed f5 to build my program, it compiled, said "Build successfull" and then VS froze. An .exe was created but when trying to run the file, it say that it's already open in system. Since then, even when I create a new project, the same thing happens. TO open the .exe again, I have to restart the compute and when I try to run it after a restart, nothing happens and it locks up again.

This all happened after I opened an example project that I got from my programming teacher. I suspected that the project might have screwed my settings but I tried reseting my settings and re-installing VS. Neither worked. I also ran ccleaner and removed all VS related folders. I have tried several fixes that I red about on this forum that seemed to be related but none of those have worked either.

When I opened a project that I created on my computer, on another computer, that screwed up VS on that computer as well so now I basically am unable to work anymore. I was logged in on my MS account on VS on both computers but could that really have anything to do with it? I am at a loss here and really need help.

I have sent an email to my teacher about it but I don't know how quickly he'll respond so I thought you guys might be able to help. Since I didn't find a similar issue on the site, I thought this might be a useful topic to solve as well.

Thank you in advance, LethalJam.

Comment: Try to post some code and more relevant information please.

Comment: I've seen things like this happen due to the automated unit test detection in visual studio. Your project name doesn't end in the word 'test' by any chance?

Comment: Do you use Avast antivirus? There have been several recent questions where Avast is causing this or similar problems.

Comment: Magisch, the code doesn't matter. Whatever project or code I build, the same thing happens.

Comment: Blastfurnace, yes I do! I'll check it out

Comment: Yes, Blastfurnace was right. I've never had this issue with avast before and I've been using it for ages... Oh well, thanks anyway!

Comment: Don't use F5 to build, use F7 or Ctrl+alt+f7, F5 is for "run in debug", whatever you are trying to build+run it is crashing your IDE.